# Ruby Watir, Dijit Widget, set value from "select list"

Tags: ruby, set, watir, dojo, selectlist

I'd like to be able to **click** (to see available options/list of accounts, seem to be hidden to start with) and then **set** a dijit widget "select_list" to a certain value.

I can find the object using

```
@@ie.element(:css, "#accountSwitcherSelect.dijitDownArrowButton").flash
#works
```

but cannot use click or set with it:

```
@@ie.element(:css, "#accountSwitcherSelect.dijitDownArrowButton").click
#no errors, but doesn't do anything

@@ie.element(:css, "#accountSwitcherSelect.dijitSelectLabel").set("Account2")    
#NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for <Watir::HTMLElement:0x4d6af60>

@@ie.element(:css, "#accountSwitcherSelect.dijitSelectLabel").send_keys("Account3")
#NoMethodError: undefined method `send_keys' for <Watir::HTMLElement:0x4d6af60>
```

In the past the site was implemented using plain html and had a select_list, so

```
@@ie.select_list(:name, "link").set(/Account1/i)
```

worked just fine.

Here's the current html behind the site:

```
<table id="accountSwitcherSelect" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitDownArrowButton dijitSelectFixedWidth dijitValidationTextBoxFixedWidth dijitSelect dijitValidationTextBox" lang="en-US" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" aria-haspopup="true" role="listbox" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode,tableNode,focusNode" style="-moz-user-select: none; width: 207px;" tabindex="0" widgetid="accountSwitcherSelect" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false">
  <tbody role="presentation">
    <tr role="presentation">
      <td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation">
        <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,_popupStateNode" popupactive="true">
          <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel " role="option">Account1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
      </td>
      <td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode">
        <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="? ">
      </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the the "select list" is similar to those on the [digit.form.Select documentation page](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Select.html), you need to:

1. Click the dropdown arrow (an input element)
2. Click the cell that has the text you want (a td element)

In your case, it would look like:

```
@@ie.input(:class => 'dijitArrowButtonInner').click
@@ie.td(:class => 'dijitMenuItemLabel', :text => /Account1/i).click
```

Here is a working example (though it relies on the dijit css files still being available online).

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "data:text/html,#{DATA.read}"
browser.input(:class => 'dijitArrowButtonInner').click
browser.td(:class => 'dijitMenuItemLabel', :text => 'Arizona').click
sleep(10)  # Just so that you can see the dropdown has changed
browser.close

__END__

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/_static/js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
        <script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: true}</script>
        <script src="https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/_static/js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        <script>require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Select"]);</script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div name="select3" value="AL" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
            <span value="AL"><b>Alabama</b></span>
            <span value="AZ"><i>Arizona</i></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Watir-Classic**

The above solution works for watir-webdriver, but not watir-classic. Clicking the dropdown (actually a table) is not triggering sufficient events to open the dropdown. As a work around, it seems you can use `send_keys` to trigger the right events.

Assuming that `browser` is opened to a page with the above html, the following will work:

```
browser.table(:id => 'dijit_form_Select_0').send_keys :enter
browser.td(:class => 'dijitMenuItemLabel', :text => 'Arizona').click
```

Note that the table in this code is the selected option (when the dropdown is closed).

Comment: Thank you Justin..  Is input element not supported by older ruby/watir?  NoMethodError: undefined method `input' for #<Watir::IE:0x4b5b770>

Comment: How old is "older"? It looks like IE#input was added in v3.0.0. If you let me know what version you are using, I can see if I find a compatible solution (assuming upgrading is not an option).

Comment: I temporarily upgraded to watir-classic-4.0.1, the input element can now be found, but is disabled..  Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException: object {:tag_name=>["input"], :class=>"dijitArrowButtonInner"}
 is disabled
    C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:334:in `assert_enable
d'
    C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:475:in `perform_actio
n'
    C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:354:in `click!'

Comment: Even after removing the disabled attribute, clicking the element does not trigger the dropdown. Will need to dig into how the dropdown works.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions on how to access the dropdown?

Comment: I added a watir-classic workaround (tested with watir-classic v3.4 and IE8). See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks Justin.  I got it to work with watir-webdriver 0.6.4, would have to figure out other issues before upgrading from watir 2.0.4 to watir-classic-4.x.